# After user input with scanner just blank line, program stops

Tags: java, arrays, line

In a program I'm making after I let the user input a scanner I create a new Array type "Instructor[]" before having a few if options for the user's integer input.
Basically it's:

```
System...println("Hello, here are your options:..);
Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean valid = false;
while(valid==false)
{
   .... make sure it becomes valid...
}
Instructor[] list = new Instructor[2];
if(user.nextInt()==1)
{
   do this
}
else if(==2)
{
  do this
}
... if( ==n)
...
else
{
   System...println("wow");
}
```

So the 3 options I want appear and if I enter a value outside the while loop works and lets me come back, but then when I enter a valid int the program stops with a blank line, I believe it's because I crate the new Instructor[] array. Thing is I need to make it outside the 3 options because I need to use the same one for each option. 
I've tried without the while loop and it still is blank, and without the Instructor[] it works, but how can I organize this so that it continues to run when I make a new Instructor[] outside the if statements?

Comment: Can you please post the entire code?

Comment: Please post your real code. I think I know what your problem is, but I can't be sure because this is just pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to prompt the user once per loop, you might want to set `user.nextInt()` equal to a variable. It looks like the way you are doing it now, the program is asking for new user input for each and every if statement. so try something like this:

```
if (input==1){
     do this
}
else if (input==2){
     do this
}
else if (input==3){
     do this
}
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes thank you! Converting the scanner to an int first has fixed the problem!